# SublimeText Output Display Finish Time

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext

I have just started using SublimeText 2 and running python scripts on it.

My output display also shows [ Finished in 0.1s ]

I do not want the output display to show this message. Can anyone help me in this regard.

Kindest Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure,

Edit this file:

`~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/Default/exec.py`

```
def finish(self, proc):
    if not self.quiet:
        elapsed = time.time() - proc.start_time
        exit_code = proc.exit_code()
        if exit_code == 0 or exit_code == None:
            self.append_data(proc, ("[Finished in %.1fs]") % (elapsed))
        else:
            self.append_data(proc, ("[Finished in %.1fs with exit code %d]") % (elapsed, exit_code))
```

And to be more specific, comment out `if exit_code == 0....` and the following 3 lines.

Comment: This solved my question of how to hide the system `path` variable on a failed build

Answer (score 7):

Simply add the

```
"quiet": true
```

option to your .sublime-build file.